# Why is Firefox's window on X11 crashing on every display configuration change?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, firefox

I am using Firefox on Ubuntu 20.10 (recently updated from 20.04 where this issue was also occurring). Every time the display configuration changes or something goes full screen (I plug in a monitor, the lock screen starts, I put the laptop to sleep), the window that Firefox is in suddenly moves behind all other windows and desktop icons (as if it was part of the desktop), and it loses its contents (everything being displayed in the window gets garbled or disappears). I have to press Alt + F4 and restart Firefox. I am running gnome 3.38.1, but it happened in 3.36 as well.

It might have started after I updated my proprietary nivida drivers, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas? Let me know if I can provide other helpful information.